# REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version not working on build with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a React app, initialized with CRA.
on my .env file I have the following env variable, to access on my application the version of the package.json file:

REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version

When I use **nom run build** with **react-scripts build**, the production build takes the env value from the .env file and shows the correct version defined on package.json.

But when I use web pack to build the production app, the version value is not injected to the env variable.

this is my web pack.config.js file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env.staging.local' })
const srcFolder = 'src'
const distFolder = 'dist'

module.exports = {
    // entry point for application
    entry: {
        app: path.join(__dirname, srcFolder, 'index.js'),
    },
    mode: 'production',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json'],
        fallback: {
            fs: false,
            crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
            stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
        },
    },

    // output file settings
    // path points to web server content folder where the web server will serve
    // the files from file name is the name of the files, where [name] is the
    // name of each entry point
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, distFolder),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '.',
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'async',
            minSize: 20000,
            minRemainingSize: 0,
            minChunks: 1,
            maxAsyncRequests: 30,
            maxInitialRequests: 30,
            enforceSizeThreshold: 50000,
            cacheGroups: {
                defaultVendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    priority: -10,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true,
                },
                default: {
                    minChunks: 2,
                    priority: -20,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'public/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: 'public/assets', to: './assets' },
                { from: 'public/favicon.ico', to: './favicon.ico' },
                { from: 'public/manifest.json', to: './manifest.json' },
                { from: 'public/robots.txt', to: './robots.txt' },
            ],
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': JSON.stringify(process.env),
        }),
    ],
    performance: {
        hints: false,
        maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
        maxAssetSize: 512000,
    },
}
```

Can someone please point out what should I do to have this value injected on the env variable as with **react-scripts build**